# measuring network quality

Tags: python, performance, networking

My network quality seems to vary quite significantly.
I'd like to monitor throughput to provide qualified statements to my provider.
Searching the internet I find [pypi.org/project/mtrpacket/](https://pypi.org/project/mtrpacket/) and the one-time throughput metering offerings such as [speedtest.net/](https://www.speedtest.net/). They also offer CLI/API, but the only UNIX system I have on site is my Raspberries, which aren't supported yet.

Could you suggest some python code and ideally a service API I could use on a Raspberry preferably in Python?

**note:** As I have influxDB and grafana running, this would allow to show the timeseries directly and apply some DA/ML algorithms on it.

Comment: You might have a look at [netio](https://web.ars.de/netio/).

Comment: @Axel Danke! but there is no API documented and reverse engineering with unknown outcome is not justifying the effort.

Comment: There is one main source file `netio.c`. No reverse engineering required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another convenient solution as a python package on:

```
https://pypi.org/project/speedtest-cli/
```

once installed with:

```
sudo pip3 install speedtest-cli
```

you can run it e.g. in a cronjob and store the data e.g. into an influxdb to show the trend via grafana or chronograf etc.